# Applescript application retains home folder name

Tags: applescript, posix

There is one line in an application that seems to maintain the home folder name.  When I move the application to another Mac it gives an error that It can't find a file with the previous home folders name in it.

If I use this it retains the previous users name in the path:
`property tracking_file : POSIX path of (path to home folder from user domain) & "file.txt"`

I changed it to:
`property tracking_file : POSIX path of (path to home folder as string) & "file.txt"`
That seeemed to update the username in the path but after saving it, if I move it to another mac the situation is the same, the previous users name is in the path for `file.txt`

This is the error: `Can't make "/Users/previous-username/file.txt" into type file. (-1700)`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Property values are evaluated at compile time.  A better approach for variable items like this would be to set the property to `missing value` and reset it to the desired value when starting up the application.

Comment: Thanks for the directions @red_menace... I'm unfamiliar with `missing value`.  Where would I use that?

Comment: It is just a placeholder of sorts, so use it like any other value, e.g. `property whatever : missing value`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I tried `property tracking_file : missing value 
property tracking_file : POSIX path of (path to home folder as string) & "script-log.txt"` But that isn't working.  I have no doubt I'm using the missing value incorrectly.  What am I missing?

Comment: Oh got it... `set tracking_file to missing value` . Thank you

Comment: Use the `property tracking_file : missing value` declaration, then somewhere in your startup (`run` handler, etc) use `set tracking_file to POSIX path of (path to home folder as string) & "script-log.txt"`.

Comment: Thanks again and glad you posted that cause my solution didn't work.  ha!  Thanks again!